# Insert the values of a combo box into an SQL Server DB table Visual Basic 2010 (Visual Studio 2010)

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

Good evening.
I want to insert data to a table in SQL DB.I have a combo box with the values "5" and "6". When you click one or the other in the combo box i want these values to be inserted in a database( MS SQL Server 2008).I also have some textboxes which are bind correnctly and have no problem. The problem is with the bindings(i guess) of the combo box. I get sql exception.

Here is a snippet. Any help would be appreciated.Thanks

```
Private Sub BindFields()
        txtSurname.DataBindings.Add("Text", ObjDataView, "surname")
        txtName.DataBindings.Add("Text", ObjDataView, "name")
        cboColor.DataBindings.Add(cboColor.SelectedValue.ToString, ObjDataView, "color")
End Sub

 Private Sub Customers_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
     cboColor.Items.Add("5")
     cboColor.Items.Add("6")

 FillDataSetAndView()
        BindFields()
End Sub


Private Sub btnAdd_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

        Dim objCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
        Dim intPosition As Integer
        intPosition = objCurrencyManager.Position

        ObjConnection.Open()
        objCommand.Connection = ObjConnection
        objCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tblCustomers" & "(name, surname, color)" & "VALUES(@name,@surname,@color);"
        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", txtName.Text)
        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@surname", txtSurname.Text)
        objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", cboColor.SelectedValue.ToString)
        Try
            objCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
        Catch SqlExceptionErr As SqlException
            MessageBox.Show(SqlExceptionErr.Message)
        End Try

        ObjConnection.Close()


        FillDataSetAndView()
        BindFields()


        objCurrencyManager.Position = intPosition
        ShowPosition()
End Sub
```

Comment: what is the exception you're getting? the details, I mean..

Comment: What has the `vba` tag got to do with this?

Comment: It hits here : objCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", cboColor.SelectedValue.ToString). NullReference Exception was unhandled. Any ideas? Thanks for the quick reply btw

Comment: I might have a slipped a tag by mistake Remou. Do you have anything to comment on the actual problem? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inspect the cboColor.SelectedValue; it is not initialized and set to nothing. Attempting to call ToString on .SelectedValue will generate a Null Reference exception.  I believe what you want is the cboColor.Text property;  this will pull whatever the current text of whatever value the combobox is currently displaying.

Comment: That did indeed fixed the null exception Art but another problem arouse. It cannot insert the second value of the combo box. With the first one (the "5") seems to be ok. Any idea?

Comment: What is the exception you are getting and on what line?  Also why are you binding the cboColor if you are populating it manually?

Comment: Art you saved me! I should not have bind them. Works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Example in C# :

```
if (comboBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Class1.str);
            con.Open();
            string query= "Insert Into Ex(Combo)Values ('" + comboBox1.SelectedItem + "' )";
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(query, con);
            com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
         }
```